# Insert Product Addons in WooCommerce via Api

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have to sync WooCommerce with other platforms. The products have some options 
that user can choose , for example size .. so I need a way to populate this data via the API but the Rest api seems does not provide this ( only attributes can be populated but they are not same, user can not pick some one of them ) and not sure which plugin to use for that.

Comment: The WooCommerce REST API is fully integrated with the WordPress REST API. So you could try to [add an custom endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) to this API.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm having roughly the same situation.

Comment: Actually it worked for me to add an custom endpoint as @user141080 suggest